# Picking 2 unique values from an infinite list

Tags: haskell

I have defined a function to get 1 prime number from an infinite list of random numbers between a lower and an upper bound:

```
randomNumbers :: Random a => a -> a -> [a]
randomNumbers bottom top = randomRs (bottom, top) $ unsafePerformIO newStdGen    

-- | Generates a random prime number of k bits length
randPrime :: Integer -> Integer
randPrime k = head $ filter isPrime ( randomNumbers (2^(k-1)) ((2^k)-1) )
```

But sometimes I'm in need of two unique prime numbers `p` and `q` where `p =! q`.

This feels completely wrong:

```
-- | Generates random prime number q until it differs from a given prime number p
randUniquePrime :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
randUniquePrime p k
    | q == p = randUniquePrime p k
    | otherwise = q
    where q = genPrime k
```

What is the most haskell'ish and functional way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you never want to use `unsafePerformIO`. Yes it has valid uses, but as a beginner you never want to touch it. So let's fix `randomNumbers` and `randPrime` first.

```
randomNumbers :: Random a => a -> a -> IO [a]
randomNumbers bottom top = randomRs (bottom, top) <$> newStdGen    

-- | Generates a random prime number of k bits length
randPrime :: Integer -> IO Integer
randPrime k = head . filter isPrime <$> randomNumbers (2^(k-1)) ((2^k)-1)
```

Now to get multiple prime numbers we can just have `randPrime` return a list of primes and filter duplicates from that list:

```
import Data.List (nub)

-- | Generates random prime numbers of k bits length
randPrimes :: Integer -> IO [Integer]
randPrimes k = filter isPrime <$> randomNumbers (2^(k-1)) ((2^k)-1)

-- | Generates random prime numbers of k bits length
randUniqPrimes :: Integer -> IO [Integer]
randUniqPrimes k = nub <$> randPrimes k

-- Now we can get any number including two unique random primes using take
-- or similar.
randPrimePair :: Integer -> IO (Integer, Integer)
randPrimePair k = (\(x:y:_) -> (x,y)) <$> randUniqPrimes k
```

In case you do not know how to work properly with `IO` without using `unsafeCoerce` here is a very short introduction:

1. If you have a value of type `IO a` and a function `a -> b` you can use

   ```
   fmap, (<$>) :: (a -> b) -> (IO a -> IO b)
   -- eg.
   nub <$> randPrimes k
   -- or
   fmap nub (randPrimes k)
   ```

   to apply that function.
2. Apply a function that takes multiple arguments to multiple `IO` values. For this there is

   ```
   (<*>) :: IO (a -> b) -> (IO a -> IO b)
   -- which you can use like this:
   getThreeLines :: IO (String, String, String)
   getThreeLines = (,,,) <$> getLine <*> getLine <*> getLine
   -- Reminder:
   (,,,) :: a -> b -> c -> (a, b, c)
   ```
3. If you have a value of a value of type `IO a` and a function `a -> IO b` you can use

   ```
   (=<<) :: (a -> IO b) -> (IO a -> IO b)
   -- or the commonly used ugly flipped variant
   (>>=) :: IO a -> (a -> IO b) -> IO b
   -- eg.
   print =<< getLine
   ```
4. Sometimes you may need to lift a pure value into `IO` for this there is `pure :: a -> IO a`. `pure` often also goes under the name `return`.

Comment: It can handle nonconsecutive duplicates: `Data.List.nub [1, 2, 1] == [1, 2]`

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex Fixed